# Is there a header pin connector with the pins in the same board plane?

Tags: connector, header

Is there a standard pitch male header pin with pins in the same plane as PCB? My goal is shown on the figure in principle, with edge mounted pins. I would prefer a header connector, but accept single pins if that's the only solution available.

Seems like a simple requirement to me (it's saving space), but I haven't seen them.
[image: What I'm looking for but with a STANDARD header pins (2.54 mm, 2 mm)]

Comment: do you mean something like [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-headers/2518654/)?

Comment: No, in that (standard) case pins are in the different (yet parallel) plane, say 1 mm above the board (assuming "the plastic" is 1 mm thick).

Comment: What you appear to be after is a PCB edge connection? Similar to what you get on RAM sticks?

Comment: Similar yes, but RAM sticks are "card edge" type which requires special mating connector, I would like to match to standard header.

Comment: What do you mean by a standard header?

Comment: E.g. Samtec TSW-104-05-G-S for 2.54 pitch, TMM-104-01-T-S for 2 mm pitch.

Comment: Oh, right, a Berg connector.  I've seen angled ones, but no in-plane ones.

Comment: Is this to plug into a socket or will it be soldered in?